# login con codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Buenas estoy armando una aplicacion con codeigniter 4, ya acabe le login y me funciona bien el problema lo tengo que por las rutas me dirije directo al login, pero quiero antes armar un index con una plantilla y de ahi redirigir con un link al login pero tengo problemas con las rutas y el controlador ya que cuando cambio el controlador para que entre primero al index luego redirijo al login con un href me sale el error 404: adjunto codigo:

Aca las rutas

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/inicio', 'Home::inicio');
$routes->post('/login', 'Home::login');
$routes->get('/salir', 'Home::salir');
```

Aca el controlador Home:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\Usuarios;

class Home extends BaseController
{

public function index()
{
    
    return view('index');
}
public function ingresar()
{
    $mensaje = session('mensaje');
    return view('login', ["mensaje" => $mensaje]);
}
public function inicio()
{
    return view('inicio');
}
public function login(){
    $usuario = $this->request->getPost('usuario');
    $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
    $Usuario = new Usuarios();

    $datosUsuario = $Usuario->obtenerUsuario(['usuario' => $usuario]);

    if (count($datosUsuario) > 0 && password_verify($password, $datosUsuario[0]['password'])){

        $data = [
            "usuario" => $datosUsuario[0]['usuario'],
            "type" =>$datosUsuario[0]['type']
        ];
    $session = session();
    $session->set($data);

    return redirect()->to(base_url('/inicio'))->with('mensaje', '1');
    }else{
    return redirect()->to(base_url('/'))->with('mensaje', '0');
    }
}
public function salir(){
    $session = session();
    $session->destroy();
    return redirect()->to(base_url('/'));
}
}
```

Aca parte de la plantilla del login

```
    <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <h1>LOGIN</h1>
      <form action="<?php echo base_url('/login') ?>" method="POST">
        <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" required="">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El archivo login se llama login.php, cree el archivo index.php el cual quiero que sea la base ahi cree un vinculo login para que redirija a login para que pueda hacer cambios.

Aca parte del index:

```
<div id="top-header">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="header-links pull-left">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +021-95-51-84</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> email@email.com</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 1734 Stonecoal Road</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="header-links pull-right">
                    
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('/login') ?>"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Si alguien tuviera alguna idea, algun error o algo que se me fue, estaria muy agradecido.
Gracias

Comment: los datos estan bien, deberias ver que tienes en el env o el config conde le dices cual es la raiz

Comment: Gracias si revise, en el config la base es: public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/store/'; ya que es el nombre de mi proyecto.

Comment: Puedes agregar la imagen del error que te envía

Comment: DAVE 
prueba usar `$baseURL = 'localhost/store/index.php';`